# return id if get_or_created inserts data, django

Tags: django, django-models

maybe it's simple question to ask but couldn't figure out how. I am inserting data with `get_or_created` and if there is a insert then trying to return that row's ID. To achieve this I tried like it below.

```
obj, created = Advertisements.objects.get_or_create(budgets_id=pid, ad_brand=ad_brand, ad_kind=ad_kind, saved_date=today) 
print(created.id)
```

even if there is an insert. it returns an error. what is the right way to get an ID in this kind of situation.

> 'bool' object has no attribute 'id'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch `get_or_create()` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

> Returns a tuple of **(object, created)**, where **object** is the retrieved or
>   created object and **created** is a boolean specifying whether a new
>   object was created.

You need to call `print(obj.id)`

Comment: okay, it's very much mine rookienessI :) thank you for the little touch! will check it after 8 min.